# Highlight polygons using comma delimited text coordinates QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, rule-based, delimiter

I am new to GIS. I have significant CAD experience and some limited Python knowledge, and am generally familiar with basic QGIS functions.

In short, I will have several CSV files containing co-ordinates which relate to some point within specific sites. I also have polygon data (sourced from the UK Land Registry) which illustrates all of the registered land parcels within a particular county.

What I need to do is use the CSV file(s) to highlight the land parcels/sites to which they refer. So for instance, if a point (from the delimited text) falls within polygon *x*, then highlight it red.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Example below, but obviously the CSV file will have many points, potentially hundreds (I've just used the Identify Features tool to highlight a single polygon to illustrate the general requirement):

[image: Example Image]

Comment: So, should the parcel be displayed in a different symbology, or do you simply want to select the parcels for further processing, or...? What exactly is the goal?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically what your are looking for is a `Spatial Join`.

1. Import the CSV file as a point layer. Delimiter, X-field, Y-field and Coordinate System are important
   [image]
2. Make a spatial join between your points and polygons using `Data Management Tools --> Join Attributes by Location...` using the Polygon Layer as the baselayer and your points as the joined layer. For the Geoemetric predicate `intersects`.
   [image]
   [image]
3. On the newly created `Joined layer` write a `Feature Filter` where you filter all the features which have no relation to your CSV data away using some field from the CSV data layer.
   [image]
4. Apply a red style on the new layer using the `Symbology`
   [image]